# Styling asp.net treeview per node

Tags: css, asp.net, treeview

I'm attempting to style a treeview where the parent node and child nodes text are displayed in different colors.

The problem is the nodes are links and are styled using CSS.

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active {
color: #823551;
```

}

That colors the child nodes the way I want but my question is how do I override the style attributes for the parent node?

Alternatively how do I apply CssClass attributes to just the Treeview control without defining the style for the entire page?

```
<Asp:Treeview CssClass="TreeView" ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowExpandCollapse ="false">
<ParentNodeStyle CssClass="parentNode" />
<LeafNodeStyle CssClass="leafNode"/>  
</Asp:Treeview>
```

I've also tried setting the ForeColor property in the ParentNodeStyle but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Update:
Generated HTML, apologies for the verbosity, its all wrapped up in DNN:

Rootnode:

```
<a class="dnn_ctr424_View_TreeView1_0 rootNode dnn_ctr424_View_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr424$View$TreeView1','s2015')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(dnn_ctr424_View_TreeView1_Data, this,'dnn_ctr424_View_TreeView1n0');" id="dnn_ctr424_View_TreeView1n0" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">2015</a>
```

Leafnode:

```
<a class="dnn_ctr424_View_TreeView1_0 leafNode dnn_ctr424_View_TreeView1_5" href="http://localhost:49357/newsletter/?newsID=5/test-dec" id="dnn_ctr424_View_TreeView1n1" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">14  December</a>
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the generated html?

Comment: Sure, update my question

Answer (score 1):

Can all the parent nodes have the same styling as each other?  [If so, this should do it.](https://jsfiddle.net/gdnauas4/)

```
.rootNode{
  color: red;
}

.leafNode {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The a, a:link, a:visited, a:active styles were overidding your suggestion which I was able to resolve by using the !important flag: